# I don't get 'Name' and 'Age' printed in logs?(error is mentiond at the end.)

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("User",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(name VARCHAR,age INTEGER(2),id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )");
            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user(name,age) VALUES('gaurav',20)");
            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user(name,age) VALUES('saurav',16)");

            Cursor c=myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user",null);
            int nameIndex=c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int ageIndex=c.getColumnIndex("age");


            c.moveToFirst();
            while(c!=null){
                Log.i("Name",c.getString(nameIndex));
                Log.i("Age", Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));  //tring to get this things in logs but instead it shows an error.
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

ERROR IS

> ::E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow
>   which has 18 rows, 2 columns.

Comment: try deleting the App's data and rerunning. The -1 indicates column not found. It also indicates only 2 columns not the 3 (id, name and age) so one is missing (hence the -1 for either age or name). Additionally checking cursor for null is useless, use `while(c.moveToNext()) { ...... }` instead and remove the line `c.moveToFirst();` (the move methods return true if the move can be made, else false hence why you can use the `while(c.moveToNext())` to loop through the cursor).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the App's data and rerunning.

The -1 indicates column not found. The message also indicates only 2 columns not the 3 (id, name and age) so one is missing (hence the -1 for either age or name). openOrCreate will open the database if it exists so any changes to the structure will not be applied (unless say you did `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN your_missing_column columntype`, which you don't want to do in repeating code as it would only work the once )

Additionally checking cursor for null is useless, use `while(c.moveToNext()) { ...... }` instead and remove the line `c.moveToFirst();` (the move methods return true if the move can be made, else false hence why you can use the `while(c.moveToNext()) {....}` to loop through the cursor).

Encapsulating in a try/catch block tends to confuse matters. So I'd suggest :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("User",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(name VARCHAR,age INTEGER(2),id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )");
    myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user(name,age) VALUES('gaurav',20)");
    myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user(name,age) VALUES('saurav',16)");

    Cursor c=myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user",null);
    int nameIndex=c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int ageIndex=c.getColumnIndex("age");

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("Name",c.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.i("Age", Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
    }
}
```